# How can I import a package that is too levels higher up? ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, class

```
project
├── __init__.py
├── package1.py
├── package2.py
└── testing
      ├── test_some_class.py
      ├── __init__.py
```

Inside `test_some_class.py`, I am trying to import a class from `package1.py` like this:

```
from ..package1 import SomeClass
```

But I run into:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

To import the package and class without error.

Comment: I do not understand the link... any chance you could post a simple solution?

Comment: Yo could you open the question again? - I need an answer and don't understand the link. Or could you provide an simple answer?